# Android CustomView behave abnormal

Tags: android, view, visibility, custom-view

I am creating an application, in which a camera is showing with an option on screen to hide and show grids on the screen. I created this grid by CustomView and it was working fine. but when I hide the grid and click show then horizontal lines are not showing... please help...

**custom view**

```
<com.***.GridLinesView
    android:id="@+id/cameraView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**OnClick Hide/Unhide Button**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            View grid = (View)findViewById(R.id.cameraView1);

            if(grid.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                grid.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else
                grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

**Custom View**

```
public class GridLinesView extends View {

    private Paint p;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;

    public GridLinesView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(1);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public GridLinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(1);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public GridLinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(1);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        int ratio = 5;
        if(width < 300 || height < 300){
            ratio = 3;
        }
        xpos = width / ratio;
        ypos = height / ratio;
        p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        for (int i = 0; i < ratio; i++) {
            p.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 255, 255));
            canvas.drawLine(0, (ypos * pass) + ratio, width, (ypos * pass) + ratio, p);
            pass++;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ratio; i++) {

            p.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 255, 255));
            canvas.drawLine(xpos + (xpos * i), 0, xpos + (xpos * i), height, p);

        }
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciable... Thank you.